# wordpress loop query to get post id and category

Tags: php, wordpress

below i my code i am unable to get `**Post id and catgory**`, what i am missing please guide me for that

<

```
?php
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'product',
    ) );  
     while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>
        <p>POST id:---><?php get_the_ID();?></p>
        <p>Category:---><?php get_the_ID();?></p>
        <br />--------------</br>
<?php endwhile;
```

Comment: you need [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: yeah pls do..  also upadted post

Comment: In your code sample you're trying to query for a post_type of **Product** - are you trying to query for an ecommerce product from something like Woocommerce? A wider explanation of your scenario would help

Comment: no not woocommcr one my theme had custom catgeory music i changes it proudct

Answer (score 0):

The post type, or post format, is actually a taxonomy, so you'll have to use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to do it.

Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(                
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'post-format-gallery',
        )
    )
);
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $myposts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $myposts->have_posts() ) {
         $myposts->the_post();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: can i also check if post has fatured image also

Comment: hey but 'terms' => 'post-format-gallery' or gallery here

Comment: Yes, you would add  `'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'` to the query args to filter for posts with a featured image.

Comment: above code is not working i thing  'terms' => 'post-format-gallery', should be something else